# CMake subdir library and main project

Tags: c, gcc, cmake

This is an example, I googled a lot for this today but I cannot find a good way for have this thing done.

For example I followed what's written in this link: http://mirkokiefer.com/blog/2013/03/cmake-by-example/

I have

```
/Build
/Src
 => main.c
  /Lib
      => File.c
      => File.h
```

I have a CMakeLists.txt in the Src dir

```
SET(SOURCES
    main.c
)
add_subdirectory(Lib)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} lib)
```

and in the Lib dir:

```
set(LibSrc
    File.c
)
set(LibHead
    File.h
)
add_library(lib STATIC ${LibSrc} ${LibHead})
target_include_directories(lib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

When I compile the project everything compile corretly, but when the gcc links the library with the rest of the project I receive an error like:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `test()`
```

It is driving me crazy... Any hints on where I'm doing it wrong? Thank you

Comment: What's the output of `make VERBOSE=1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your [`target_link_libraries`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/target_link_libraries.html) command is missing the list of dependencies.  I guess in your case, you just want to link "lib", so you need to change this to:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} lib)
```

As an aside, you're missing a `$` before `{CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` in the line

```
target_include_directories(lib PUBLIC {CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Comment: Yes, you are right about both. But actually they are just typos during the copy and paste of the code. This is a snippet of a more complex CMakeLists.txt I will edit my question and correct the typos. Thank you for noticing them.

Comment: OK - but the `target_link_libraries` line is *still* wrong!  The target defined in the subdirectory "Lib" is actually `lib`, not `Lib`.  Apart from that, your setup looks fine.  If that's the case, then maybe you actually haven't defined `test()` anywhere - only declared it?

Comment: It is defined in the .c file. I see it and it compile. The headers are seen from outside the library, if I remove the lib from the target_link_libraries gcc complains about the fact it can't see the header files.

Comment: Looks like something was wrong with the cmake build directory. I delete it and restart the build and everything works. the linking part is working correctly.